# error when bundle Fedora 2.0 ruby-2.0.0-p481 [ x86_64 ]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rvm

I'm getting this error, when I run: $ bundle

```
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Using rake 10.3.1
Using i18n 0.6.9
Using multi_json 1.10.0
Using activesupport 3.2.18
Using builder 3.0.4
Using activemodel 3.2.18
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using journey 1.0.4
Using rack 1.4.5
Using rack-cache 1.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using hike 1.2.3
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.2.2
Using actionpack 3.2.18
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.4
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 3.2.18
Using arel 3.0.3
Using tzinfo 0.3.39
Using activerecord 3.2.18
Using activeresource 3.2.18
Using addressable 2.3.2
Using authlogic 3.2.0
Using multi_xml 0.5.2
Using httparty 0.10.0
Using json 1.7.7
Using nokogiri 1.5.6
Using uuidtools 2.1.3
Using aws-sdk 1.8.0
Using bcrypt-ruby 3.0.1
Using ffi 1.3.1
Using childprocess 0.3.6
Using websocket 1.0.6
Using libwebsocket 0.1.7.1
Using rubyzip 0.9.9
Using selenium-webdriver 2.27.2
Using xpath 1.0.0
Using capybara 2.0.2
Using coderay 1.0.8
Using coffee-script-source 1.4.0
Using execjs 1.4.0
Using coffee-script 2.2.0
Using rack-ssl 1.3.4
Using rdoc 3.12.2
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 3.2.18
Using coffee-rails 3.2.2
Using columnize 0.3.6
Using yamler 0.1.0
Using configatron 2.9.1
Using hashie 1.2.0
Using cover_me 1.2.0
Using database_cleaner 0.9.1
Using debugger-ruby_core_source 1.1.6
Using debugger-linecache 1.1.2

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/nisevi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_control_frame_t.method_id in method.h... no
checking for rb_method_entry_t.called_id in method.h... yes
checking for vm_core.h... yes
checking for iseq.h... yes
checking for insns.inc... yes
checking for insns_info.inc... yes
checking for eval_intern.h... yes
checking for struct iseq_line_info_entry in vm_core.h,iseq.h... yes
checking for if rb_iseq_compile_with_option was added an argument filepath... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling breakpoint.c
compiling ruby_debug.c
ruby_debug.c:27:14: error: conflicting types for ‘rb_iseq_compile_with_option’
 RUBY_EXTERN VALUE rb_iseq_compile_with_option(VALUE src, VALUE file, VALUE filepath, VALUE line, VALUE opt);
          ^
In file included from ruby_debug.c:4:0:
/home/nisevi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/debugger-ruby_core_source-1.3.7/lib/debugger/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.0.0-p481/vm_core.h:650:7: note: previous declaration of ‘rb_iseq_compile_with_option’ was here
 VALUE rb_iseq_compile_with_option(VALUE src, VALUE file, VALUE absolute_path, VALUE line, rb_block_t *base_block, VALUE opt);
       ^
ruby_debug.c: In function ‘save_call_frame’:
ruby_debug.c:493:31: warning: operation on ‘debug_context->frames’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
     debug_context->frames = REALLOC_N(debug_context->frames, debug_frame_t, debug_context->stack_len);
                           ^
ruby_debug.c:506:53: error: ‘rb_control_frame_t’ has no member named ‘bp’
     debug_frame->info.runtime.bp = GET_THREAD()->cfp->bp;
                                                 ^
ruby_debug.c: In function ‘set_thread_event_flag_i’:
ruby_debug.c:698:7: error: ‘rb_thread_t’ has no member named ‘event_flags’
     th->event_flags |= RUBY_EVENT_VM;
       ^
ruby_debug.c:698:24: error: ‘RUBY_EVENT_VM’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     th->event_flags |= RUBY_EVENT_VM;
                    ^
ruby_debug.c:698:24: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
ruby_debug.c: In function ‘debug_event_hook’:
ruby_debug.c:727:16: error: ‘ID_ALLOCATOR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     if (mid == ID_ALLOCATOR) return;
            ^
ruby_debug.c:780:96: error: ‘rb_control_frame_t’ has no member named ‘bp’
     if (debug_context->frames[debug_context->stack_size - 1].info.runtime.bp <= thread->cfp->bp)
                                                                                            ^
ruby_debug.c:952:102: error: ‘rb_control_frame_t’ has no member named ‘bp’
         if (debug_context->frames[debug_context->stack_size].info.runtime.bp <= GET_THREAD()->cfp->bp)
                                                                                                  ^
ruby_debug.c: In function ‘context_frame_id’:
ruby_debug.c:1756:8: warning: unused variable ‘id’ [-Wunused-variable]
     ID id;
    ^
ruby_debug.c: In function ‘context_frame_file’:
ruby_debug.c:1823:134: error: ‘rb_iseq_t’ has no member named ‘filename’
     return(GET_FRAME->info.runtime.cfp->iseq->filename);
                                                                                                                                  ^
ruby_debug.c: In function ‘copy_scalar_args’:
ruby_debug.c:1861:24: error: ‘rb_control_frame_t’ has no member named ‘dfp’
         val = *(cfp->dfp - iseq->local_size + i);
                    ^
ruby_debug.c: In function ‘context_copy_locals’:
ruby_debug.c:1922:46: error: ‘rb_control_frame_t’ has no member named ‘dfp’
             rb_hash_aset(hash, str, *(cfp->dfp - iseq->local_size + i));
                                          ^
ruby_debug.c:1940:62: error: ‘rb_control_frame_t’ has no member named ‘dfp’
                     rb_hash_aset(hash, str, *(block_frame->dfp - iseq->local_table_size + i - 1));
                                                          ^
ruby_debug.c: In function ‘context_jump’:
ruby_debug.c:2395:53: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
         if ((cfp->pc - cfp->iseq->iseq_encoded) >= (cfp->iseq->iseq_size - 1))
                                                 ^
ruby_debug.c:2407:70: error: ‘rb_iseq_t’ has no member named ‘filename’
     if ((cfp->iseq != NULL) && (rb_str_cmp(file, cfp->iseq->filename) == 0))
                                                                  ^
ruby_debug.c:2409:38: error: ‘rb_iseq_t’ has no member named ‘insn_info_size’
         for (i = 0; i < cfp->iseq->insn_info_size; i++)
                                  ^
ruby_debug.c:2411:30: error: ‘rb_iseq_t’ has no member named ‘insn_info_table’
             if (cfp->iseq->insn_info_table[i].line_no != line)
                          ^
ruby_debug.c:2422:56: error: ‘rb_iseq_t’ has no member named ‘insn_info_table’
                 cfp->iseq->iseq_encoded + cfp->iseq->insn_info_table[i].position;
                                                    ^
In file included from ruby_debug.c:9:0:
ruby_debug.c: At top level:
/home/nisevi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/debugger-ruby_core_source-1.3.7/lib/debugger/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.0.0-p481/insns_info.inc:695:1: warning: ‘insn_name’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 insn_name(VALUE insn)
 ^
/home/nisevi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/debugger-ruby_core_source-1.3.7/lib/debugger/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.0.0-p481/insns_info.inc:701:1: warning: ‘insn_op_types’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 insn_op_types(VALUE insn)
 ^
/home/nisevi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/debugger-ruby_core_source-1.3.7/lib/debugger/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.0.0-p481/insns_info.inc:707:1: warning: ‘insn_op_type’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 insn_op_type(VALUE insn, long pos)
 ^
ruby_debug.c: In function ‘context_frame_file’:
ruby_debug.c:1824:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
make: *** [ruby_debug.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/nisevi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/debugger-1.2.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/nisevi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.0.0/debugger-1.2.3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing debugger (1.2.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install debugger -v '1.2.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

this is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "aws-sdk"
gem "authlogic"
gem "bcrypt-ruby"
gem "foreigner"
gem "jquery-rails"
gem "memcache-client"
gem "mysql2"
gem "rack"
gem "rack-attack"
gem "rack-utf8_sanitizer"
gem "rails", "~> 3.2.11"
gem "rb-readline" 
gem 'rollbar', '~> 1.2.6'
gem "simple_form"
gem "thinking-sphinx", "~> 2.0.14"
gem "trollop"
gem "unicorn"
gem "uuidtools"
gem "will_paginate"

group :assets do
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.2.0"
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.2.0"
  gem 'therubyracer', :require => 'v8'
  gem 'uglifier'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "dotenv-rails"
  gem "pry"
  gem "pry-debugger"
end

group :test do
  gem "capybara"
  gem "database_cleaner"
  gem "factory_girl"
  gem "faker"
  gem "mocha", :require => false
  gem 'cover_me', '>= 1.2.0'
end
```

and I'm using ruby-2.0.0-p481 [ x86_64 ]
I would like to know what is happening and if anyone can help I'm gonna be really gratefull, and I keep writing because stackoverflow complains about the code that I've written and the poor text that I have in this question!

Comment: https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger/issues/125#issuecomment-43353446

Comment: seems like an incompatbility version or missed dependency of debugger module. check dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby 2.0 does not supports pry-debugger use byebug instead,
for you just change 'pry-debugger' to gem 'pry-byebug' in your Gemfile and it will work.